How to create a figure legend in matplotlib with just one line while plotting subplots?
I have this code to plot 4 sub bar plots:
 def plot(self, concat_series, save_plot):
        grouped = concat_series.groupby("metric")

        fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(grouped))
        i=0
        for name, group in grouped:
            group.plot.bar(ax=axes[i], x='network', legend=False)
            axes[i].set_title(name)

            axes[i].grid(True)  # Add grid lines (optional)
            i+=1

        plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust spacing (optional)
        legend = fig.legend(loc="lower center", ncol=4, title="Coordinates")
        plt.savefig(save_plot)
        plt.close()


What gives me this:

As the for subplots have same legend notations, I would like to plot the legend with just one line instead of 4 repeated lines. How can I achieve this?

Using get_legend_handles_labels with one of the Axes:
handles, labels = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
legend = fig.legend(handles, labels, loc="lower center", ncol=4, title="Coordinates")

Output with sample data:

You can adjust the location with bbox_to_anchor, something like:
legend = fig.legend(handles, labels, loc="lower center", ncol=4, 
                    title="Coordinates", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1))
plt.savefig(save_plot, bbox_inches='tight')


Another option may be to use a constrained layout:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(grouped), layout='constrained')
# plt.tight_layout() 
legend = fig.legend(handles, labels, loc="outside lower center", 
                    ncol=4, title="Coordinates")
plt.savefig(save_plot)



Thank you very much!!!! But let me bother you a bit longer. How place the legend bellow the X axis to avoid overlapping?

I suspected you would ask that.

Since Matplotlib v3.7 you can also specify a string to place the legend below the x-axis, if you use constrained layout https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/legend_guide.html#figure-legends

Thanks you very much! Only one extra line and two extra parameters to solve the problem.

You can try recording the legends using group.index.tolist() and pass it to fig.legend().
Your code may look like:
Code
def plot(self, concat_series, save_plot):
    grouped = concat_series.groupby("metric")
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(grouped))
    L = []
    for i, (name, group) in enumerate(grouped):
        group.plot.bar(ax=axes[i], x='network', y='value', legend=False)
        axes[i].set_title(name)
        axes[i].grid(True)
        L.extend(group.index.tolist())

    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.legend(L, loc="lower center", ncol=len(L), title="Coordinates")
    plt.savefig(save_plot)
    plt.close()

